# how to initialize js upon modal launch

Tags: javascript

I essentially have a modal in which I need to use some js, the modal is being rung up by using some vue.js code, the inner modal contents are using some regular js.

having these two separated at first worked fine, by just throwing my additional logic-js into with the vue.js I get these errors:

https://jsfiddle.net/8z37f15j/10/

i tried separating the files and setting the `window on.(load/ready)` here and there to no luck

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: item1 is not defined
    at projects-modal.js:25
    at dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Projects</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> <!-- jquery -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script> <!-- vuejs -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/projects-modal.js"></script> <!-- custom js -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>-projects-</h1>

        <ul id="button-container">
            <li>
                <a id="html-modal-button" @click="showModal = 'html-modal'">
                    <img class="htmllogo" src="images/HTMLLogo.png">
                    <div class="html-text-block">
                        <h2>HTML</h2>
                        <p>My web projects</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            <htmlmodal v-if="showModal === 'html-modal'" @close="showModal = false"></htmlmodal>
        </li>
    </ul>


    <!-- MODAL SECTION -->
    <script type="text/x-template" id="html-modal-template">
    <transition name="modal">
            <div class="modal-mask">
                <div class="modal-wrapper">
                    <div class="modal-container">
                        <slot name="body">
                            <div id="wrapper">
                                <div id="project-list">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="item1">item1</li>
                                        <li id="item2">item2</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                 <div id="image-container">
                                <div id="image-area">
                                  <img src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png">
                                </div>
                                <div id="description-area">
                                    just a placeholder text for when nothing has been chosen.
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <button class="fas fa-angle-up modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')"></button>
                            </div>
                        </slot>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </transition>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
// CREATE THE DOM COMPONENT
Vue.component('htmlmodal', {
    template: '#html-modal-template',
    });

    Vue.component('csmodal', {
        template: '#cs-modal-template',
    });


    // START THE APP
    new Vue({
        el:'#button-container',
        data: {
            showModal: false
        }
    });

    const desc_area = document.getElementById('description-area');
    const image = document.querySelector('img');
    const map = new Map();

    // register item element as a key and object with corresponding description / image as value
    map.set(item1, { desc: 'test1', img: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tHGIZ4rLbOY/hqdefault.jpg' });
    map.set(item2, { desc: 'this is a test2', img: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cf/2e/d2/cf2ed20d5a0f941dc64b2aa388bfa884.png' });

    // you can bind on click handler for example
    const list = document.querySelector('ol');
    list.addEventListener('click', event => {
      // if element that was registered in our map triggered the event
      if (map.has(event.target)) {
        // change text of description area
        desc_area.textContent = map.get(event.target).desc;
        // change src of the image
        image.src = map.get(event.target).img;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is your error? The console is clear in the fiddle. Also, you'll probably get a faster response if you can simplify your fiddle -- stripping away anything that isn't related to the error you're seeing will help others (and may help you unravel the mystery first!)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you are loading your page, since your code is in the head it gets executed before the DOM is ready. This is purely what I speculate, but since JS fiddle is a website that is already loaded, the DOM might already be ready for commands.

So instead of using on("load") do on("ready") / .ready(). This will wait for the DOM to be initialized then you can call the function. Again I am unsure about this but have a go and let me know how it goes.

Comment: i added the 'ready' and yes it got rid of the errors but along with the logic

Comment: I believe `$(window).on('load')` (Assuming this is jQuery) actually runs later than `.ready` but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Try moving the OnLoad statement to your Body instead of your head, just to test

Comment: @Cornelis im unsure what you mean by moving it to the body

Comment: i found that by having my vue.js on load, and the logic on ready i lose the errors but i also lose my logic functionality, is there like a step-by-step breakpoint in js kinda like in C#?

Comment: yes, you can use the code: "debugger;" to break it. However, it will only break when the console is open. So you will need to use chrome or firefox

Comment: okay so essentially, its ready my vue.js fine, but since my vue isnt activated so my modal isnt on the page yet, my logic is having a hard-time finding an item in the modal, so how to i like "ready" that logic when i press a button, or in this case, open my modal?

Comment: If I understand what you are doign correctly then you should be able to save your logic as a function, and when the button is pressed just call the function. Or you can add a listener to your thing 

   `.on ('click')`. And important to use _on()_ instead of _.click_ because the latter doesn't listen to elements created after load.